# ErrorException in Grammar.php line 39: Array to string conversion

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, request, laravel-5.1

This is my store function in CategorieController.php

```
public function store(Request $request) {
  Categorie::create([
  'name'=>$request['name'],
  ]);
  return redirect::to('/categorie');
}
```

and this is what I have in my model Categorie.php

```
class Categorie extends Model { 
  protected $table =['categories'];
  protected $fillable=['name'];
}
```

but when I try to save my categorie into database I get this error:

> ErrorException in Grammar.php line 39: Array to string conversion

Answer (score 9):

`$table` variable used in your model is of type `string`.

```
protected $table = 'categories';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make changes in two places:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    Categorie::create([
        'name' => $request->get('name'), // 1st place
    ]);

    return redirect::to('/categorie');
}
```

And:

```
class Categorie extends Model { 
    protected $table = 'categories'; // 2nd place
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

**Explanation:**

**$table** attribute of **Model** class which **Categorie** class extends from accepts a table name as string (Not Array) to link this model to it's corresponding table in database.